# Generating a random matrix with large spark (i.e., each $k$-tuple of columns is linearly independent)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, random-matrices

Let $F$ be a field, and let $m, n, k$ be positive integers. Is there an efficient algorithm to compute a uniformly random $m \times n$ matrix $A$ over $k$ such that each $k$-tuple of columns of $A$ is linearly independent?

This question is related to the notion of [spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_(mathematics)), since the condition of $A$ is equivalent to $\text{spark}(A) \geq k + 1$. The spark is difficult to compute (NP-hard), however it might be that generating $A$ can be done efficiently. It also seems to me that the question is related to the generation of random points in general position, although I'm not sure about that.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I assume the ideas in this paper could be used to show that your problem is planted-clique hard: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09646

Comment: If the field is countably infinite, is there such a thing as a uniformly random matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You could start from a directed graph ($m$ vertices, $n$ edges) where you know that the shortest cycle has length $k$. Then the incidence matrix $A\in\{0,\pm 1\}^{m\times n}$ has spark $k$.

You may construct such a graph by appending a loop to a tree graph, and for any graph the length of the shortest cycle can be found in polynomial time.

See section 3.2 of [Tillmann's "Computing the Spark".](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/papers/tillmann_sparkcomputation_preprint.pdf)

Comment: This is very interesting. I don't think it answer the "uniformly random" part though. Especially because the entries of the matrix are in 0,-1,+1 instead of the full field F.